# Chromecast 2, no cast devices found on 16.04 with latest Chromium

Tags: 16.04, chromium, chromecast

I just tried the #media-router method available online. No luck. Chromium is not able to find the cast device, at all. The TV and Chromecast 2 are ON and online. What to do ?

Also, is there any method other than using Chromium browser to work with 16.04 ? I have Chromecast 2nd Generation for media.

Just to add, my browser gets hanged and crashes at times when I try to connect to Chromecast.

Chromium version : 56.0.2924.76

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 20.04, I solved my chromium cast tab's "no devices found" by turning off my wired connection and selecting the same wi-fi network as the chromecast device is set to. For some reason having both wi-fi and a wired connection on at the same time causes the chromecast device not to be connected to.

Comment: The Chromecast docs clearly state it MUST be on the same network as the one trying to cast to it.

Comment: What the Chromecast docs do NOT state is that on some systems such as mine, the device must be EXCLUSIVELY connected on the wi-fi and nothing but the wi-fi, of course on the same wi-fi network as Chromium, but not on a wired connection at the same time. (which my system legitimately uses in other applications without any conflicts)

Comment: Mine does but glad you worked it out.